# Teamcity - Octopus: Packages not found

Tags: teamcity, nuget, octopus-deploy

I have quite a complex TeamCity-Solution.

Configuration "tcBuild" builds and creates nuget-packages, as well as it modifies the version number of the assembly.
Configuration "tcDeploy" depends on "tcBuild", takes the nuget-packages and send it using octopus.

tcBuild just works fine and also creates the wanted packages.

tcDeploy throws the following error for each package:

```
2014-01-28 14:50:05.5826  ERROR  Unable to download package: 
Octopus.Platform.Deployment.ControlledFailureException: Could not find package Packagename 1.1.0.903 in feed: 'http://localhost/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/'
   at Octopus.Shared.Packages.PackageDownloader.FindPackage(Int32 attempt, PackageMetadata packageMetadata, IFeed feed, IActivity log) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1116bd9da9e239fd\source\Octopus.Shared\Packages\PackageDownloader.cs:line 155
   at Octopus.Shared.Packages.PackageDownloader.AttemptToFindAndDownloadPackage(Int32 attempt, PackageMetadata packageMetadata, IFeed feed, IActivity log, String cacheDirectory, IPackage& downloadedPackage, String& path) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1116bd9da9e239fd\source\Octopus.Shared\Packages\PackageDownloader.cs:line 130
   at Octopus.Shared.Packages.PackageDownloader.AttemptToDownload(PackageMetadata metadata, IFeed feed, IActivity log) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1116bd9da9e239fd\source\Octopus.Shared\Packages\PackageDownloader.cs:line 89
2014-01-28 14:50:05.5826  ERROR  Error in DownloadAndPushToTentaclesOrchestrator-OCw-lDdz+eWP@SQ-PESY0002-F9FA8F1A while receiving bedf70c1-1f30-496f-91ca-aba6cc956042
```

(where "packagename" is the name of the package)
The version number of the error message is the same as of the nuget packages' "core-properties"-folder.

Other, quite similar builds on that machine work just fine. Tell me if I need to provide more information.

Comment: You'll definitely need to provide more information. The mostly likely reason why you'd run into this issue is if your NuGet artifacts are named differently than what your deployment step is expecting.

Comment: I agree with Mike - can you show the filenames of all packages generated by the tcBuild configuration *before* they get pushed to the NuGet endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create one tc project to package which triggers another project to deploy. We ended up with this approach so that we can deploy the latest build to octopus. Good luck.